# What does \D do in Perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

In some code I am maintaining, I have found the expression:

```
$r->{DISPLAY} =~ s/\Device//s;
```

What surprises me is that it matches both device and Device!

I have not found any mention of \D in the documentation, only \d.

Can someone clarify please...

Comment: You almost certainly want a case-insensitive match (`s/Device//si`) rather than this obfuscated use of `\D`...

Comment: It's also useful to know that you run `perldoc perlre` on your command line, or go here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html.

Comment: I'd call this an "incorrect" use of `\D` rather than an "obfuscated" use... That regex will also match "crevice", "Levice", and even "#evice", not just "device" and "Device".

Comment: Reading the rest of the code (not shown), it appears that a case sensitive match is needed with "Device". I think the stray "\" is a cut and paste error. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\D` is the negation of `\d`, i.e. it matches anything that is not a digit.

Comment: @Roger If you like sepp2k's answer, you should click the checkmark to the left, to signify that this answer answered your question.

Comment: @Roger If you meant to checkmark sepp2k's answer, I believe you made a mistake.. you put the checkmark on my answer.

Comment: @TLP: Don't complain! You did the more helpful answer, got the accept. That's the way the system works.

Answer (score 11):

In that regex, `\D` looks like a typo. It works for both `d` and `D`, only because it matches any character that is not a digit (0-9).

A more appropriate regex (if the intent is to match "device" or "Device"), is:

```
s/(d|D)evice// # one way
s/[dD]evice//  # another way
```

The `s` option is also a bit odd. From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

```
s   Treat string as single line. (Make . match a newline)
```

And there is no such matching going on in that line.

Comment: Yes, I think the '\' was a cut and paste error, as a match with Device was required...

Comment: Strange copy/paste error.. it does not seem to belong there in any context I can think of, except perhaps from a windows path, e.g. "c:\Device"...

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer, However, there's documentation in [perldoc perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) about it. See the information about [Backslash sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences).

It's also mentioned in [perldoc perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.htm) and in the regular [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.htm) under *Using character classes*. However, in those two sections, it's rather buried.